# Is there any feasible way to integrate any real payment processing system (not cryptocurrency) while developing a solution using hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am developing a micro money-lending platform where I am using hyperledger -composer to model the business network, but I am getting stuck on how to implement the payment processing system in my solution as hyperledger-composer doesn't have any currencies associated with it.

How can I do this?

Comment: what in particular are you trying to model, a 'Money' type?  Think you need to define the 'crux' of your issue and what you want to be able to do !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric might not be the best tool for this task. If you want to use it, you can use it just like a relational database, with your users as Participants, other entities as Assets etc etc. But you can't use it for passing money from one person to another -- you'll have to use other means.